# fileUpload phonegap plugin does not work in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using fileupload phonegap plugin to upload jpeg file to my server from iPad.
It is not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
window.plugins.fileUploader.uploadByUri('http://192.168.1.54:8080/POC/fileUploader', 'file://Documents/flower.jpg', null, 'myPhoto', 'flower.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 
        function(result) {
            console.log('Done: ' + result);
        }, 
        function(result) {
            console.log("Error: " + result);
        } 

    );
```

In fileUploader.js file, I put an alert below the uploadbyuri method. But its not displaying. That means that method is not calling.

What mistake I have done?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this plugins its works for me.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/FileUploader

and if its not working please specify proper error that you are getting for upload image.

Answer (score 0):

Me too had the same situation. FileUploader worked fine in cordova1.9.0. When i changed to cordova2.7.0 face the same situation. After a long time messing with the issue, I made it work  by remnaming "Phonegap" to "cordova" in fileuploader.js file which is in www folder.

```
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function()  {....
```

to

```
cordova.addConstructor(function()  {....
```

and

```
 return PhoneGap.exec('FileUploader.' + method, callback + '.success', callback + '.fail', callback + '.progress', server, file, fileKey, fileName, mimeType, params);
```

to

```
 return cordova.exec(null,null,"FileUploader", "uploadByUri",[ callback + '.success', callback + '.fail', callback + '.progress', server, file, fileKey, fileName, mimeType, params]);
```